# Molar absorption coefficient of H2SO4(aq) for UV-vis spectrophotometry

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry, databases

I am wondering if there is anything in the literature that can tell me what is the molar absorptivity (i.e. molar extinction coefficient) of aqueous sulfuric acid at a given wavelength (in my case, I am interested in $\lambda_\mathrm{max}(\mathrm{ferroin}) = \pu{508 nm}$).

In addition, is there a good resource in the literature to look up these values for common substances? I haven't yet been able to find anything of the sort.

Answer (score 4):

I never ran into uv absorption data for (aqueous) sulfuric acid and I doubt that there is any absorption at $\lambda$ = 508 nm.

There is an old paper by K. F. Palmer and D. Williams in *Appl. Optics*, **1975**,*14*, 208-219 ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.14.000208)) on the optical properties of sulfuric acid droplets with respects to the composition of clouds on Venus and a more recent one from the group of J. B. Burkholder in *Phys. Chem. A*, **2003**, *107*, 1112-1118
([DOI](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp0263626)) on *Vibrational and Electronic Spectroscopy of Sulfuric Acid Vapor*. Both, while interesting and therefore mentioned here, are not relevant for your experiment.

My suggestion is simple:

Measure your ferroin sample in aqueous sulfuric acid (or whatever solvent is required) and use the same solvent as a blank. Most spectrometers will automatically perform the subtraction of the blank from your sample!

Concerning a (free) source of UV-vis absorption data, there is the [NIST Chemistry WebBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/).